# Group by in complex query with cases

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table:

```
Visit (FromId, ToId, VisitTime)
```

where FromId and ToId are FKs to table

```
UserProfile (uid, name, age ...)
```

As a user with my UID I want to select all profiles I have visited or who visited me in one result set ordered by VisitTime and with the indication of the "direction of the visit".

I get data using this select:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN a.FromID = 'yourIDHere' 
            THEN c.Name
            ELSE b.Name
    END Name,
    CASE WHEN a.FromID = 'yourIDHere' 
            THEN c.Age
            ELSE b.Age
    END Age,
    a.VisitTime,
    CASE WHEN a.FromID = 'yourIDHere' 
            THEN 'You'
            ELSE 'Friend'
    END DirectionOfVisit
FROM    Visit a
    INNER JOIN UserProfile b
        ON a.FromID = b.Uid
    INNER JOIN UserProfile c
        ON a.ToID = c.Uid
WHERE   'yourIDHere' IN (a.FromID, a.ToID)
ORDER   BY a.VisitTime
```

Now it prints (pseudo output)

```
Jack (id1) | IN |12.12.2012
Jack (id1) | IN |11.12.2012
Jack (id1) | IN |11.12.2012
Jack (id1) | OUT | 13.12.2012
Jack (id1) | OUT | 12.12.2012
Michael (id5) | IN | 5.12.2012
Michael (id5) | OUT | 6.12.2012
Michael (id5) | OUT | 5.12.2012
```

I would like the list to be like this:

```
Jack | IN | 12.12.2012 (the most recent)
Jack | OUT | 13.12.2012 (the most recent)
Michael (id5) | IN | 5.12.2012 (the most recent)
Michael (id5) | OUT | 6.12.2012 (the most recent)
```

I know the GROUP command would solve it but it's too complex for me (beginner).

Comment: can you include the query that you have executed in your question?

Comment: Please see the link on the first line of my question - didn't want to duplicate it here. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use GROUP BY along with an aggregate function to get the result. Since you want the most recent date for each `name` and `type` (IN/OUT), then you can use the `max()` aggregate function on the date column.  You will then use a GROUP BY on the other columns you want to return:

The basic syntax will be:

```
select
  name,
  type,
  max(date) date
from yourtable
group by name, type;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0dbfd4/1)

If you want to return the max date with your existing query, you can just expand the query to use:

```
select name, age, max(VisitTime), DirectionOfVisit
from
(
    SELECT  CASE WHEN a.FromID = 'yourIDHere' 
                THEN c.Name
                ELSE b.Name
        END Name,
        CASE WHEN a.FromID = 'yourIDHere' 
                THEN c.Age
                ELSE b.Age
        END Age,
        a.VisitTime,
        CASE WHEN a.FromID = 'yourIDHere' 
                THEN 'You'
                ELSE 'Friend'
        END DirectionOfVisit
    FROM    Visit a
        INNER JOIN UserProfile b
            ON a.FromID = b.Uid
        INNER JOIN UserProfile c
            ON a.ToID = c.Uid
    WHERE   'yourIDHere' IN (a.FromID, a.ToID)
) d
group by name, age, DirectionOfVisit;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4bbd4a/3)

Comment: The schema is included in the linked question, didn't want to duplicate it here. It's more complex than your answer unfortunatelly. Thank you.

Comment: @PetrB You should include all of the required details in your question here.  You should be able to modify this in your existing query, I was offering up a solution to demonstrate how you use GROUP BY.

Comment: You also need an order by clause.

Comment: @DanBracuk If they want the data displayed in a specific order then yes an order by would be required.

Comment: I edited the question to include all details

Comment: @PetrB You can easily implement a GROUP BY with an aggregate with your existing query, see my edit